# Difference between “most of the people” and “most people”

Tags: articles, definite-article, prepositional-phrases

> a. In this era, **most of the young people** are impatient and this leads to crime.

My teacher corrected to

> b. In this era, **most young people** are impatient and this leads to crime.

My question is, when to say “most of the young people”
and when to say “most young people”?

What is the difference?  When should I use **most of the** vs. **most**?

Comment: Probably without *things* you can use "most of the". For example, "Most of the *time*, I like to have ice cream for dessert." You can't say "most time" here.

Comment: You could say "Most time**s**, I like to have ice cream." meaning I often like to have ice cream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the definite article *the* only works if you're talking about a specific group of young people.

> Most of the young students at this school learn English.

If you're talking about young people in general, then you need the null article.

> Most young people are impatient.

With an singular noun, you need to use “most of the …”, e.g. “he ate most of the cake”. Grammatically, the situation looks different. But there is actually a reason behind this. In “most of the young students at this school”, *most* qualifies a specific domain (the young students at this school). In “most of the cake”, *most* qualifies a specific domain (this one cake). In “most young people”, *most* qualifies the non-specific group of all young people. Since there is no specific domain, there is no definite article.

Comment: Do you claim that "Most young students at this school learn English." is wrong?

Comment: @user1425 No. I didn't discuss it in my answer, but that sentence also works. “Young students at this school” can be treated either as a general domain (young students) with a restriction (so “most young students at this school”) or as a specific domain (“most of the young students [who are] at this school”). The meaning is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. "most young people" is the short form of "most of the young people". But when a shortened form has been found it is the preferred one.  Google Ngrams shows this [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20young%20people%2C%20most%20of%20the%20young%20people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20young%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20the%20young%20people%3B%2Cc0)