# When to omit "The"?

Tags: grammar

Please check the following two sentences:

> **The boys** in my class are nice.
>
> **Boys** in my class are nice.

Which one is correct and why? And what does each sentence imply?

Comment: Please note that you should do some research first and indicate what your research revealed. You should also search ELL, because there are [many questions here that deal with the use of the definite article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-article), and I strongly suspect that this question has been asked before.

Comment: Such as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84954/difference-between-most-of-the-people-and-most-people?rq=1).